# Exporting to PDB seems to lose aromaticity

Tags: export, import, chemistry

I have a molecule with the following SMILES:

```
ClearAll[sml];
sml = "O=C(NCC1=CC(NC(C2=CN=C3C=CC=CN23)=O)=C(C)C=C1)NC4=CC=CC(F)=C4";
```

The plot looks as follows:

```
sml // RightComposition[
    Molecule[#, IncludeHydrogens -> True] &,
    MoleculePlot[#, ImageSize -> Large] &
]
```

[image: Original molecule showing aromatic bonds]In particular, please note the presence of aromatic bonds.

Now, following the [export example at the bottom of the page for PDB files](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/PDB.html) in the help manual, I attempt to export the molecule to a PDB file:

```
ClearAll[coords, atoms];
{coords, atoms} = sml // RightComposition[
    Molecule[#, IncludeHydrogens -> True] &,
    {MoleculeValue[#, "AtomCoordinates"] &, AtomList /* Map[First]}, Through
];

Export[
    FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "mol.pdb"}],
    {{QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[coords, "Picometers"]]}, {atoms}},
    {{"AdditionalCoordinates", "AdditionalAtoms"}}
];
```

The export happens correctly (or at least so it appears), and I get a PDB file.

But when I load the PDB file, I find that the molecule has lost its aromatic bonds:

```
"mol.pdb" // RightComposition[
    Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], #}], {"PDB", "Molecule"}] &,
    MoleculePlot[#, ImageSize -> Large] &
]
```

[image: Molecule imported from the PDB file]In addition, the oxygen atoms appear to have lost their double bonds as well.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you using version 12.1?  If so there is a workaround.

Comment: @JasonB.yes, I have the latest version, 12.1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- PDB files often contain no bond information at all, and when they do they don't contain bond types
- Perceiving bond types from 3D geometry is a relatively expensive operation, which is fine for small molecules (<100 atoms) but really time-consuming for large proteins
- The PDB importer for the `"Molecule"` import element does not do bond-order perception by default, and there isn't a documented option to turn it on.
- The XYZ importer has a documented option `"InferBondTypes"` which should be added to the PDB importer, perhaps with an `Automatic` setting that switches behavior based on the atom count.
- There is an undocumented option though to turn on the bond order perception for the PDB importer, which can be used in version 12.1

```
sml = "O=C(NCC1=CC(NC(C2=CN=C3C=CC=CN23)=O)=C(C)C=C1)NC4=CC=CC(F)=C4";
element = {"PDB", "Molecule"};
sml // Molecule // 
    ExportString[#, element]& // 
    ImportString[#, element, "UseOpenBabel" -> True]& //
    MoleculePlot
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Is there a way to include bond information in the PDB export to being with, so that I won't have to resolve ambiguities later?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the file format to be honest.  Reading [here](http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format-content/format33/sect10.html#CONECT) it seems that you can specify the presence of bonds but not their type. Using a format like "SDF" makes it easier to round-trip a molecule.

Comment: Once again, very helpful to know. I am trying to dock the molecules produced by my WL code using something called AutoDock. Since I am not a chemist, I know almost nothing about these various formats. I will check if AutoDock can accept SDF files.